# Rabies vaccination, two 3rds of the required course

Tags: vaccination, injections, rabies

As some of you may be aware, the Rabies vaccination requires a set of 3 doses over a period of 1 month. I have "maybe" had 2 of those 3 jabs. The nurse can see on my records that 2 doses have been administered back in 2004. **As rabies is a one off vaccination and it lasts for life, does this mean simply having the additional 3rd dose is all that is required?**

I cannot remember back to 2004 to know if I really had 2 or 3 doses so sadly we'll just have to go by what is on record. I'm just intrigued as to how this works. **Because the course was not complete, does this render the vaccination useless, and does a full 3 part course need to be re-administered to ensure its effects?**

Just to disclaim, I will not be using the answer to this question as sufficient medical advice, I will leave that to the nurse for my up coming appointment. I am curious however, about the technical aspect of having a  partial vaccination.

Many Thanks

Comment: I still don't know how or why, however after speaking to the Nurse on Monday, she assures me the 2 previous vaccinations in 2004 would still be active and that the 3rd dose, given on Monday, would complete the treatment. Any takers? Anything to the contrary?